# Difference between Collections.reverseOrder vs custom comparator

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

I expect the two code snippets to produce the same result, yet they don't. Why?
The only difference is the Comparator passed to the PriorityQueue constructor.

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PriorityQueueTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
    int[] arr = {2,3,9,8,4};
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      pq.add(arr[i]);
    }
    while(pq.size()>0) {
      System.out.println(pq.poll());
    }
  }
}
```

Output (correct / expected):

```
9
8
4
3
2
```

```java
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class PriorityQueueTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> a>b ? 0 : 1);
    int[] arr = {2,3,9,8,4};
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
      pq.add(arr[i]);
    }
    while(pq.size()>0) {
      System.out.println(pq.poll());
    }
  }
}
```

Output (wrong / unexpected):

```
2
9
8
4
3
```

Comment: What do you think `a>b ? 0 : 1`  does?

Comment: It compares a with b. If a is greater, returns 0, causing it to be ordered before b. I expect this to produce a descending ordered priority queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparators must return 3 states: negative, 0 or positive, and must be self consistent such that `compare(a,b)` has same sign as `-compare(b,a)` when a!=b, and zero if `a.equals(b)`.

Your comparator does not satisfy these conditions. You are fortunate your answer works, but if you omit the `0` case in other comparators you may have issues in future.

Instead use:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>((a,b) -> a==b ? 0 : a>b ? -1 : 1);
```

The above returns the order of elements you expect as for `Collections.reverseOrder()`.

Answer (score -1):

What I was missing is that returning a 0 in the comparator indicates that the values are equal.

Changing comparator to the following orders things correctly

```java
(a,b) -> a>=b ? -1 : 1
```

Comment: This misses the case when a == b, which should return 0.